# How to create SQL STATEMENT to split date & add string between the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I want to split the date and add desired strings in between the parts of date.

```
DECLARE @date112 varchar(10), @batchdate varchar(10)
SET @date112 = ''
SET @batchdate = ''
SELECT @date112 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) -- date format 
YYYYMMDD
```

This is my expected result : "2019年 10月 31日" or "2019year 10month 31day"

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server please tag your question `[sql-server]`. The `[sql]` tag signifies the general SQL language. Different RDBMS products have different syntaxes and different features. Accurate tagging increases your chance of getting timely and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 112) + 'year ' +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 5, 2) + 'month ' +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 2) + 'day';
```

This prints:

```
2019year 10month 31day
```

### Demo

To set the result of this query to a user variable:

```
@date112 = (SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 112) + 'year ' +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 5, 2) + 'month ' +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 2) + 'day');
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, the demo output the i result wanted, Thanks. But how i set variable @batchdate equal to the output?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with this output?  If you need to generate it from a query, then you already have 3 answers which show you how to do this.  If you're doing this from a proc or a UDF...well that's another story.

Comment: Basicaly im using internal company sofware where im running the sql script. I need to set a variable equal the output, so that i can call out the variable anytime i want to check the output. When i assign the output to @batchdate for instance, i can pass the output to other model.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FORMAT` function like so:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy\y\e\a\r MM\m\o\n\t\h dd\d\a\y') -- 2019year 10month 31day
     , FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'yyyy年 MM月 dd日')                   -- 2019年 10月 31日
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are using sql server
so you can use year, month and day function and then concat

```
select cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) + ' year '+ 
cast(month(getdate()) as varchar)+' month '+
cast(day(getdate()) as varchar)+'day'
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b58924283bc7a4b498798b57949103c4)